# How does Drupal generate form ID for a form?

Tags: 7, forms

Following is the code snippet I used to generate a the User Profile edit form:

`print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_profile_form'));`

However, I could not find the declaration of the `'user_profile_form' form id` anywhere in the Drupal system. So I assumed that it is generated dynamically, but I am not sure.

So, If it is already defined, Where is it defined?
and if it is generated dynamically then how does Drupal generates these Form IDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user_profile_form` is defined in `user.pages.inc` file in `user` module directory.

The id of the form is the function name which generate the structure of the form in Drupal System. When we call `drupal_get_form`, it call function name to build the form array.

There is a function `drupal_prepare_form` in `form.inc` in `includes` directory of the Drupal root.

> `drupal_prepare_form` function prepares a structure of the form array
>   and adds required elements, executes any `hook_form_alter` functions
>   and optionally inserts a validation token to prevent tampering.

Code Snippets to generate form id:

```
if (!isset($form['#id'])) {
    $form['#id'] = drupal_html_id($form_id);
  }
```